# Enviar dois trângulos para um vertex shader. OpenGL, C++, GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Estou aprendendo na faculdade processamento gráfico com OpenGL no C++. Estamos usando as bibliotecas GLFW e GLEW. O meu programa, consiste de criar dois triângulos em partes diferentes da janela. Eu criei um array com as coordenadas do triângulo, e dois VBO e um VAO para ele. Depois eu quero aplicar uma translação a este triângulo para imprimi-lo em  outra parte da tela, usando o segundo VBO e o mesmo VAO.

O meu problema aqui é o seguinte: 
Eu enderecei os dois triângulos no VAO, um na posição(location) 0 e outro na 1.:

```
//4- Cria os vértices e seu VBO e VAO. Define a cor a partir de um Uniform
void SceneManager::setupScene()
{
// Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Positions                    
        -0.25f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.25f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    };



    GLuint VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);



    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)

                                                            GLint colorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "color");
    assert(colorLoc > -1);
    glUseProgram(shader->Program);
    glUniform4f(colorLoc, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

    triangulo2(*vertices);

}
```

Triângulo 2:

```
 void SceneManager::triangulo2(GLfloat arrayVertices) {

        //Variável que via armazenar o VBO do triangulo2
       GLuint VBO2;
            glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);

            //Vincula o VAO único
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);

            //Inicializa o VBO2 e gera seus atributos
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrayVertices), &arrayVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            //Ponteiro de atributo de posição desse triângulo. VAO
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)


    GLint colorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "color");
    assert(colorLoc > -1);
    glUseProgram(shader->Program);
    glUniform4f(colorLoc, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

}
```

Trecho onde eu mando eu VAO para o vertex shader:

```
void SceneManager::render()
{
    // Clear the colorbuffer
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    posicionaTriangulo2();

    if (resized) //se houve redimensionamento na janela, redefine a projection matrix
    {
        setupCamera2D();
        resized = false;
    }
    //Busca o VAO e desenha na tela.
    // Draw container
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    //drawElements é quando estou usando o EBO.
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}





   Só que eu não sei como passar corretamente os dois locations para o meu programa vertex shader. Sei que o objeto gl_Position da GLSL pode ser usado no meu vertex shader para processar as posições dos vértices de um objeteo passado ao shader, mas não sei como fazer quando eu passo mais de um objeto à esse shader.
```

Tentei usar duas gl_Position, mas ao fazer isso, ao invés de aparecer somente um triângulo como antes, nada apareceu na tela.

Alguém pode dar uma luz? Não tem material de qualidade sobre isso, não tem tutoriais decentes...

Esse é meu arquivo do Vertex Shader:

```
version 440 core

//Posições do primeiro triângulo
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

//Posições do segundo triângulo:
layout (location = 1) in vec3 posicao2;

uniform vec4 color;  

out vec4 ourColor;

uniform mat4 model1;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * model1 * vec4(position, 1.0f);

//Quando eu adicionei este gl_Position, nada mais aparece na tela.
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(posicao2, 1.0f);

    ourColor = color;
}
```

Esta é a função "posicionaTriângulo2()", onde eu busco a matriz model no vertex shader (essa á a matriz onde eu coloco as transformações, nesse caso), e coloco nela algumas transformações para serem aplcadas no Vertex Shader ao meu triângulo setado no VAO.

```
void SceneManager::posicionaTriangulo2() {
    // Render scene
        shader->Use();

    // Create transformations 
    //Esse método cria uma matriz4, mas não tem parâmetros... ONDE ELES SÃO DEFINIDOS? É a glm que o define?
    //A MATRIZ É PASSADA PARA O VERTEX SHADER
    model = glm::mat4();
    //model = glm::rotate(model, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime()*5, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f));
    //model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 1.0, 2.0));
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f));


    //Aplicar no rotate para uma rotação específica de 90 graus: glm::radians(90.0f)


    //EXEMPLO DO OPENGL:
    //trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    //trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));

    // Get their uniform location
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "model");

    // Pass them to the shaders
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

}
```

Comment: O VAO armazena o estado do um buffer para desenho. Provavelmente, você não irá conseguir desenhar os 2 triângulos definidos em buffers diferentes no mesmo VAO. Ou você armazena os todos os vértices no mesmo buffer ou utiliza 2 VAOs (uma para cada objeto). A variável `gl_Position` é uma variável pré-definida no *shader* e utilizá-la mais de uma vez não irá produzir o resultado que você espera

Answer (score 4):

Existe uma função ali chamada posicionaTriangulo2(...), não tem a implementação dela ali mas me parece que você ainda não entendeu o conceito do OpenGL moderno.

A ideia do OpenGL é colocar todas as informações do que vai ser desenhado num array linear, vértices, cores, normal, etc. Com esse array na mão você faz o upload dessa informação para a GPU, do lado do vertex shader você basicamente ajusta os vértices e do lado do fragment shader você ajusta as cores de cada pixel. Pense em CPU / GPU como cliente / servidor.

Uma vez feito o upload da informação para a GPU, você vai usar o cliente para solicitar ao servidor que renderize a informação, basicamente você diz: desenha começando na posição X do array, cada polígono usuará Y espaços do array e depois você vai pular N posições do array e continue até acabar o array.

Para desenhar 2 triângulos separados você tem algumas opções diferentes:

- guardar 2 arrays separados para cada triangulo e realizar o upload individualmente (é o mais fraco em performance)
- usar o glDrawElements, nele você vai fazer upload dos vértices onde não importa a ordem no array, pq quando você solicitar que seja desenhado é necessário informar justamente essa ordem (os índices) que serão desenhados
- usar uma parada chamada "primitive restart", não recomendo a utilização dele pq é algo bem mais recente e consequentemente não está disponível em qualquer versão do OpenGL, sendo bem mais restritivo quanto à plataforma

Se você tá falando que não tem material de qualidade é porque você não conhece esses dois sites:

- https://open.gl/
- https://learnopengl.com/

Esses dois sites são simplesmente fantástico para ajudar quem quer aprender OpenGL, seja nível iniciante ou até mesmo avançado.

Comment: Incluí a implementação da função 'posicionaTriângulo2()'.

Comment: Reparaste que eu peço pra GPU desenhar os dois triângulos (um com a model de transformações e outro sem), lá no meu Vertex Shader? Mas ela só desenha a última gl_position, que é o triângulo transformado

Comment: Sua explicação teórica clareou muita coisa. Já estou dando mais atenção ao learnopenGl também. Vou fazer o tutorial com calma. EU já conhecia, mas achei confuso num primeiro momento. Na verdade ele é bem didático, só requer paciência.

Comment: Mas poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu usaria o drawElements nesse caso?

Comment: Pensei dessa forma:  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, VAO);             Sendo o segundo parâmetro o número de elementos (o que se define por elemento aqui?).  Mas o quarto parâmetro não pode ser um VAO... É um ponteiro, mas não sei o que colocar alí.

Comment: 1. vc entendeu essa parte errada, o gl_position, no vertex shader, só irá guardar um valor, essa função main do VS é chamada uma vez para cada vértice

Comment: 2. Recomendo começar pelo https://open.gl/ ele é mais simples

Comment: 3. já faz um tempo que eu não escrevo código em opengl, mas se vc acessar essa página aqui vai conseguir entender bem: https://open.gl/drawing

Comment: 4. o fato de você ter entendido o shader errado muda muita coisa